# "Unconscious" versus "nonconscious" in everyday dialogue

Tags: meaning, adjectives, prefixes, speech

These words have subtle distinctions in related research fields, but even there are often considered interchangeable or just an matter of tradition/trendiness in a particular field.
Since I am a bit entrenched in that environment, I don't have perspective on what is common outside of academia.

In normal, everyday conversation, which is more common? If they are both used, do they have commonly understood distinctions in meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I know, *unconscious* stands for something, or better yet someone who is usually conscious, but currently temporarily unconscious. For example when you hit your head and fall down unconscious.

> After the accident I was unconscious for hours.

On the other hand, *nonconscious*, which isn't used very often, stands for something what's never conscious. Like a plant, a tree, or for the sake of the argument, a rock.

> In these horrible winter temperatures the trees are lucky to be nonconscious.

Comment: ... and that leaves "subconscious" ... :)

Comment: I don't think you can mix up that one with any of those in my answer, can you?

Comment: ha, no.  Just pointing it out as filling in the next relevant definition (advanced cognitive processing that occurs automatically without awareness).  However, I do think that "unconscious" is often used for all three definitions, and "nonconscious" for both of the last two.

Comment: ... which was the meaning I originally had in mind when I posted this question.  I am laughing, because apparently, it applies to neither.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can meaningfully talk about trees being "lucky" in the same sentence as pointing out that they're not even sentient enough to feel their own pain.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think I can call them lucky from my own perspective without their feeling the same, but that's a rather philosophical question.

Comment: Hmm. Could rocks not also be "lucky"? Or only things that are alive? What about a comet that "luckily" doesn't collide with anything?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't mean to argue, I mean c'mon, you're 3 times my age and you have a degree in linguistics. I don't think I could tell you what's right and what's wrong, but I really believe this works. If luck is defined as "an event or a series of events happened by chance", then yeah, either believe in God and say that trees were created on purpose by a higher being, therefore destroy the word "luck" completely, or be an atheist and state that "what happens in the world is a series of events defined by chance," or whatever. And here comes the philosophy again.

Comment: Ah, I'm just yanking your chain! :) Of course you're right that you *can* speak of nonsentient or inanimate things being "lucky". But the less self-awareness/personal identity that thing has, the more I think it's metaphorical usage. Where as you say, "luck" is from the speaker's perspective, not the thing being spoken of. I wasn't meaning to be contentious either - just trying to flag up that the meaning of "lucky" shifts according to the referent. And - as you rightly point out - it may also reflect the speaker's philosophical stance anyway.

Answer (score 1):

*Nonconcious* pretty much flatlines against *unconcious* in Google NGrams, as one might expect.
[image]

I'm not going to present any particular semantic distinctions. I'm sure there will be conflicting distinctions, and personally I don't think the word *nonconscious* has sufficient currency to be worth defining anyway, outside of specialised contexts where it's effectively "trade jargon" to avoid the connotations of *unconscious/subconscious*.

Comment: Nonconscious is the preferred term in many (most?) modern academic contexts. You are right, I did not use Google NGrams, I just did a basic Google search and read the Wikipedia page.  Thank you for pulling this up.

Comment: @Angada: I'm not an academic in any of the modern fields that would use it, but I think in general *nonconcious* simply means *lacking any element of conciousness* in those contexts. A thing that never lived or thought could be *nonconcious*, just as it could be *nonliving* (though we're more likely to hyphenate that one).

Comment: that is helpful insight, thank you.  I would never have thought of that, as, in my field, it means what I now think most would call "subconscious."  But it makes sense.  I knew I was out of touch with common usage.

Comment: @Angada: I know *subconscious* isn't normally used in fields like cognitive psychology these days, partly because it's a vague term with unwanted connotations from a largely-discredited past. A layman might think of the *subconscious* as some kind of "inner persona" that generates dreams, for example, but I don't think any serious researcher would want those connotations.

Comment: yes, exactly.  So, what word do you think would best communicate to a layperson the automatic environmental processing that occurs in the brain outside of conscious awareness?  I academia, I would say nonconscious.  But apparently that mean "never conscious" in the real world.  This is exactly the point of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think *nonconscious, unconscious*, and *subconscious* all mean the same thing: mental processes that people are not consciously aware of.

According to Freud's Topology of Mind, there are three levels of mind: The Conscious Mind (reality), The Preconscious Mind (Morality, our beliefs, values, and ideals), and The Subconscious Mind (Pleasure, what people want: food, sex, possessions, power, etc.). The preconscious can be brought to the consious mind easily, but the subconscious cannot. We are completely unaware of the subconsious.

For instance, habits are completely subconsious automatic processes that are guided by beliefs, expectations, and rewards put in place by our society. *Nonconscious, unconscious*, or *subconscious* would be correct to use — but personally, I think *subconscious* is best because it suggests we are still affected at this level of mind, where *unconscious* or *nonconscious* suggest we cannot be influenced by our surroundings.

Answer (score 0):

*Nonconscious* is a cognitive term, and is unawareness. *Unconscious* is a psychoanalytic-Freudian term, mainly emotional.

Comment: Casualty departments deal with *unconscious patients* all the time, and don't believe Freud invented the term.